# android: set up simplest opengl es app

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

i am looking for some sample code or tutorial that sets up the most basic opengl es application.

for example, just do glClear() in the renderloop.

i have already been searching the web but all i found was either out of date or too much and too complicated.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, have you tried the new "resources" tab at the android developers home? There's a nice tutorial showing the ( they name it... ) [most simple opengl-es app](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/glsurfaceview.html). Shouldn't be too hard to start from that point.